# What's a local solution in SVAR setting?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

I'm reading a text about the $A$-Model in SVAR modelling, and the author states that the restrictions on the $A$ matrix have to comply with the conditions:

$ A^{-1}\Sigma_{\epsilon}(A^{-1})^T=\Sigma_{u}$ and $C vec(A)=c$, where the sigma matrices are covariance matrices of error terms.

So, clearly in general we'll have, due to the first equality, a non-linear system.

Now the author states that the system of equations needs to at least have a unique local solution...

What's a local solution in this setting? I've heard of local solutions in the lingo of ODE's, or even of a local maximum, but never in this setting. If we had a recursive relation, I would understand the analogy, but we don't...

Any help would be appreciated.